# WP8 LongListSelector - re-assigning ItemsSource has no effect

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm using the new Windows Phone 8 `LongListSelector` control, which has its `ItemsControl` assigned to a `List<Group<object>>` as so:

```
    List<Group<PlacePoint>> searchResults; 

    async void doSearch()
    {
        this.searchResults = await SearchHelper.Instance.getSearchResults(txtSearchTerm.Text);
        longList.ItemsSource = this.searchResults;
    }
```

Unfortunately, the second time that I search, re-setting the .ItemsSource property has no effect and the control simply displays the old List.

How can I change the binding?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would seem that re-assigning longList.ItemsSource does not have any effect, whether this is a bug or by design I can't say.

However, an easy workaround is simply to use an ObservableCollection> instead and then work with this collection rather than re-assigning the ItemsSource.

Sample code:

```
    ObservableCollection<Group<PlacePoint>> searchResults = new ObservableCollection<Group<PlacePoint>>();


    public SearchPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        longList.ItemsSource = this.searchResults;
    }

    async void doSearch()
    {
        List<Group<PlacePoint>> tempResults = await SearchHelper.Instance.getSearchResults(txtSearchTerm.Text);

        // Clear existing collection and re-add new results
        this.searchResults.Clear();
        foreach (Group<PlacePoint> grp in tempResults )
        {
            this.searchResults.Add(grp);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you upvote this answer please remember to upvote the question too!  I couldn't find any answers to this issue when I searched online.

Comment: SearchHelper.Instance how to get this? I typed it in code but its showing error. Any extension needed?

Comment: `SearchHelper` is just a line of sample code, you should replace it with your own method that returns a `List<Group<YourObject>>`  The rest of that method shows you how you would then clear the existing collection and re-add your results.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it helps to set the ItemsSource to null and then to your result right after.

Comment: While that's correct, the correct solution is to use the ObservableCollection instead.

Comment: Define the "correct solution". The fact of the matter is that using Observable collection to remove and re-add all the items raises A LOT of events and can cause a huge overhead. Simply clearing out the entire itemssource to trigger a full refresh and setting a new itemssource after is often cheaper.
If you really want to discuss "correct solutions", we are talking about fixing the bug in WinPhone so you wouldn't have to do all this at all but merely set the new itemssource. But that's not working so lets focus on the simplest and cheapest >workaround<.

Comment: Silverlight and WPF also requires to explicit null the ItemsSource. And the real overhead is in the rendering, not in firing the CLR evens. By resetting the ItemsSource you potentially lose virtualization.

Comment: @dotMorten Any idea if this fixes the issue in Windows Phone as well?

Answer (score -1):

You need to define your doSearch() method using **async** for await to function properly.

Try declaring you method like this:

```
private async Task doSearch() {

}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure *await* calls won't compile in a non-*async* function - maybe he just forgot to put the *async* here...

Comment: I did forget, thanks for the heads up - this would have been better as a comment to the original question really rather than a proposed answer.\