# LongListSelector cannot change ItemsSource

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, itemssource, longlistselector

I can't seem to be able to change the *ItemsSource* in *LongListSelector*. After doing some research, it appears that *LongListSelector* ignores any changes in *ItemsSource*. Am I correct?g
If yes, is there a workaround?

This what I'm trying to do. I have an option to sort the City list either by country or cities. Something like this:

```
var groupByCountry = from City in App.ViewModelCity.Items
                                group city by city.GroupByCountry into c
                                orderby c.Key
                                select new Group<Currency>(c.Key, c);

var groupByCity = from City in App.ViewModelCity.Items
                                group city by city.GroupByCity into c
                                orderby c.Key
                                select new Group<City>(c.Key, c);
```

SO basically both are the same, just the grouping is different. My idea was to simple change the *ItemsSource* to either **groupByCountry** or **groupByCity**, depending on the user choice. Unfortunately, changing the *ItemsSource* has no effect. It simply won't update. Only when the app is restarted (with the preferred source stored) the *LongListSelector* is updated.

So is there a way to force *LongListSelector* to update the *ItemsSource*? If not, what would be a good workaround?

Comment: Try writing it as (from City in...).ToList(); Maybe deferred execution is the problem here.

Comment: This [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650788/wp8-longlistselector-re-assigning-itemssource-has-no-effect) seems to be the work around

Answer (score 0):

I develop in WP7, I set the ItemSource to null before the real assignment so that UI will update for new ItemSource.

```
LongListSelectorA.ItemsSource = null;
Binding b;
b = new Binding("CollectionInViewModel");
LongListSelectorA.SetBinding(LongListSelector.ItemsSourceProperty, b);
```

Give it a shot, wish you luck. :)